# Building a .csv based on user input

Tags: python, csv, input

I need to add to a .csv file based on user input. Other portions of the code add to the file but I can't figure out how to have it add user input. I'm new to python and coding in general.

I have other portions of the code that can merge or draw the data from a .csv database and write it to the separate file, but can't figure how to get it to take multiple user inputs to write or append to the outgoing file.

```
def manualentry():
        stock = input("Enter Stock #: ") #Generate data for each column to fill in to the output file.
        VIN = input("Enter Full VIN: ") #Each line asks the user to add data do the line.
        make = input("Enter Make: ")
        model = input("Enter Model: ")
        year = input("Enter Year: ")
        l8v = input("Enter L8V: ")
        print(stock, VIN, make, model, year, l8v) #Prints the line of user data
        input4 = input("Append to inventory list? Y/N") #Asks user to append the data to the output file.
        if input4 == "Y" or input4 == "y":
            with open('INV.csv','a', newline='') as outfile: #Pull up a seperate csv to write to, an output for collected data
                w = csv.writer(outfile) #Need to write the user input to the .csv file.
                w.writerow([stock, VIN, make, model, year, l8v]) #<-This is the portion that seems to fall apart.
                print("INVENTORY UPDATED")
                starter() #Restarts whole program from begining.
        if input4 == "N" or input4 == "n":
            print("SKIPPING. RESTARTING....")            
            starter() #Reset
        else:
            print("Invalid entry restarting program.")
            starter() #Reset
starter() #R E S E T !
```

Just need the user inputs to be applied to the .csv and saved there. Earlier portions of the code function perfectly except this to add to the .csv file. It's to fill in missing data that would otherwise not be listed in a separate database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some improvement in the code.

1. You can use a looping condition like `while` or `for` instead of recursion
2. You can open your csv file at the start of the code instead of doing it everytime
3. You can come up with a word say `stop` to stop the loop, close the file and exit
4. You can use `str.lower() == 'y'` to cover for both `y` and `Y`, upper and lower case

The code will then look like

```
import csv

def manualentry():

    #Open csv file at start
    outfile = open('INV.csv', 'a', newline='')
    w = csv.writer(outfile)  # Need to write the user input to the .csv file.

    #Everything wrapped in a while True loop, you can change to any loop accordingly
    while True:
        stock = input("Enter Stock #: ")  # Generate data for each column to fill in to the output file.
        VIN = input("Enter Full VIN: ")  # Each line asks the user to add data do the line.
        make = input("Enter Make: ")
        model = input("Enter Model: ")
        year = input("Enter Year: ")
        l8v = input("Enter L8V: ")
        print(stock, VIN, make, model, year, l8v)  # Prints the line of user data
        input4 = input("Append to inventory list? Y/N")  # Asks user to append the data to the output file.
        if input4.lower() == "y":
            w.writerow([stock, VIN, make, model, year, l8v])  # <-This is the portion that seems to fall apart.
            print("INVENTORY UPDATED")
        if input4.lower() == "n":
            print("SKIPPING. RESTARTING....")
        #If you see stop, stop writing, close the file and exit
        if input4.lower() == 'stop':
            print('Not writing anymore! Stopping')
            outfile.close()
            exit()
        else:
            print("Invalid entry restarting program.")


#Call manualentry
manualentry()
```

Comment: This is just a small snippet of the code, I felt it unwise to include the rest of the code for the context of what I'm trying figure out. I cut the other 2/3 out to showcase the section of the code that seems to not be working. Would it help to show the entirety of it?

Comment: So I assume you know about loops :D Because from this piece it felt you cannot ask the user to reinput so I added a loop, please add the full part

Comment: I'm having issues getting this portion of the code to write to a .csv using the standard .csv module. I've edited the main post to show that it exits from an infinite loop and is only accessed if the upper portion of the program fails to pull up data from another database. This section is supposed to write missing data into a .csv.

Comment: I have updated the code making some minor changes here and there, have a look @BrandonToolbelt and let me know if you have doubts

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use user input controlled while loop to recursively get user input and then you can exit depending on the user choice

```
user_input = 'Y'
while user_input.lower() == 'y':
    # Run your code here
    user_input = input('Do you want to add one more entry: Enter [Y/N]')
```

Comment: I will implement this in future builds of the program, and I thank you for this snippet, but it's not helping the general sense of the problem. I can't get this portion of code to take the user inputs and add them to a .csv file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import csv


def boo():
   stock = input("Enter Stock #: ")  # Generate data for each column to fill in  to the output file.
   VIN = input("Enter Full VIN: ")  # Each line asks the user to add data do the line.
   make = input("Enter Make: ")
   model = input("Enter Model: ")
   year = input("Enter Year: ")
   l8v = input("Enter L8V: ")
   print(stock, VIN, make, model, year, l8v)  # Prints the line of user data

   input4 = input(
    "Append to inventory list? Y/N  || anything else to exit")  # Asks user to append the data to the output file.

   if input4 == "Y" or input4 == "y":
       with open('INV.csv', 'a',
              newline='') as outfile:  # Pull up a separate csv to write to, an output for collected data

          w = csv.writer(outfile)
          w.writerow([stock, VIN, make, model, year,
                    l8v])  # Need to write the previously pulled up line to new csv
          print("INVENTORY UPDATED")
          user_input = input('Do you want to add one more entry: Enter [Y/N]')
          if user_input.lower() == 'y':
              boo()
          else:
              exit()
boo()
```